# spl_autoload_register instantiate classes

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

We know that autoloading your classes is saving time and lines of codes, however. I must instantiate that class with `$config = new config();` in order to use that loaded class.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include $class . '.class.php';
});
```

Is it possible to load all my classes with `spl_autoload_register` and then instantiate all those classes:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include $class . '.class.php';
    $class = new $class;
});
```

Comment: I think you've missed the point of autoloading.... autoloading exists to include a class file when you instantiate a new class object, not to actually instantiate the class itself (that's done by your use of the `new` keyword in your code outside of the autoloader

Comment: What is the practical use case of *instantiating all classes‽* Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was wondering if it was possible due to the fact that I do not have to use `new` everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't make any sense since autoload is called whenever you instantiate an object, and not for instantiating new objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll continue reading about autoloading.